# Scroll to top of the page using jquery animate

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I want to put to the top bottom of the page which should scroll the page to the top. However I want the scrolling process to have animated effect. I think it is possible by using animate but have no idea how to ?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The way is pretty simple. Put a button at the bottom of the page and write an event something like this

```
$('#spnTop').on("click",function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow', function () {
        alert("reached top");
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mYQN6/) for this

Comment: my alert("reached top"); is called twice. Is it the same for you guys too?

Comment: You will probably need a `event.preventDefault();` if you do it on a link.

Answer (score 7):

You can animate the `scrollTop` property of the `html, body`

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: "0px"
}, 800);
```

I suggest you do some research/reading before you ask trivial questions like these. Google can help you out before all of us can.

Comment: And Google often points to Stack Overflow for the answer. All questions/answers, trivial or not, belong here.